# jwt has no attribute encode during deployment on render

Tags: python, deployment, render

I am encountering an issue when deploying my Flask app on the Render platform. Locally, the application runs successfully, but upon deployment, I am facing the following error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'encode'`

The error is specifically pointing to the line where I use the jwt.encode function. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm="HS256")
    return encoded_jwt
```

I have verified that the jwt module is installed both locally and on the Render platform. Locally, the application works without any issues. However, on Render, I am encountering this attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed proper jwt package

```bash
pip install pyjwt
```

Comment: its work locally but not on render platform during deployment

Comment: AttributeError: module 'jwt' has no attribute 'encode' - are you getting exactly this error ? and also check once again  if it is present in the python virtual environment you are working with.

Comment: yes error is correct i used virtual env locally there not thr error, but when i deploy app i got error

Comment: Activate your virtual environment and do pip list, if it is not there you will get the error mentioned

Comment: activated my virtual env but in local there not get any error app run properly but during deployment only that time i got error with jwt'

Comment: What does pip list give in production server ?

Comment: it gives list of lib with versions

Comment: is pyjwt not there in the list ?

Comment: pyjwt is present in list